Why Prisma insert on explicit many-to-may relation not working
I'm trying to build a chat application. Following is the schema
model Conversation {
    id     Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
    name   String? @db.VarChar(100)
    // owner of the conversation
    user   User    @relation(name: "conversationOwner", fields: [userId], references: [id])
    userId Int

    users ConversationUser[] @relation(name: "conversationUsers")

    messages Message[] @relation(name: "conversations")

    createdAt DateTime @default(now()) @map("created_at") @db.Timestamp(0)
    updatedAt DateTime @default(now()) @map("updated_at") @db.Timestamp(0)

    @@map("conversations")
}

model ConversationUser {
    conversation   Conversation @relation(name: "conversationUsers", fields: [conversationId], references: [id])
    conversationId Int
    user           User         @relation(name: "conversations", fields: [userId], references: [id])
    userId         Int
    removedBy      User?        @relation(name: "conversationRemovedBy", fields: [removedById], references: [id])
    removedById    Int?

    unseenMessageCount Int @default(0) @db.TinyInt

    joinedAt DateTime  @default(now()) @map("joined_at") @db.Timestamp(0)
    leftAt   DateTime? @map("left_at") @db.Timestamp(0)

    @@id([userId, conversationId])
    @@map("conversation_user")
}

Following is the code to insert a record (add a user to the conversation)
return this.ps.conversation.update({ // Prisma service in Nest.js app
      where: {
        id,
        userId,
      },
      data: {
        users: {
          create: [
            {
              userId: 5,
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    });
    // no ts error here

When this code is executed, following error is throws
→ 75   return this.ps.conversation.update(
api  | An operation failed because it depends on one or more records that were required but not found. No 'Conversation' record (needed to inline the relation on 'ConversationUser' record) was found for a nested create on one-to-many relation 'conversationUsers'.

What causing this error?

Your database don't existed record for query id and userId in conversation table.

This was the case indeed. So silly mistake that caught me up :(. Thank you for the help
